# Can a Brother HL-L2395DW printer do scan to direct email?

Tags: printer, network-printer, scanner, multi-function-printer, brother-printer

Is it possible for a Brother HL-2395DW printer to directly email a scan?  I have the printer configured to send email to my (SMTP-AUTH protected) email server, and verified (via the web access page) that the printer can send a test email to any address via that SMTP server.

But the instructions for the printer only talk using the email client on some network-local-to-printer computer as the way to send a scan via email.

Is there any hidden/non-obvious option to get the printer to use the configured SMTP server to email scans?

Comment: So if you press the `Scan` button and then the `up` or `down` arrow and select the `E-mail` option, does that give you an option to type in an email address by chance?

Comment: Here's the manual but it sounds like there is an option to scan and send as attachment but it's not clear if there's an option to type in an email address from the printer panel or not and another "Advanced" method that you have some configuration through maybe an app you install some machine that can connect to the scanner and use **ControlCenter** to configure accordingly but that may just scan to a folder location and then open with whatever email client you use ready to be sent but attached to a blank email: http://download.brother.com/welcome/doc100802/cv_mfcl2750dw_use_oug_a.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Turns out there **is** a way to directly email, though it still does not appear it can be done by using a specified mail server, more's the pity.

1. Hit "Scan"
2. When the touchscreen gives you the choice between "to PC" and "Web Services", pick "Web Services"
3. Then pick "Scan to Email" (or "Easy Scan to Email").
4. Now you can enter an email address and do the scan and the scan will be directly emailed to that address.

Looking at the headers of the received email I see it going through Amazon SES.  Interestingly, I don't see any indication in the headers that it went through a Brother server first (though I assume any such Received headers could be stripped out in whatever SES processing Brother has set up).

TL;DR - Doesn't look like you scan directly to email using an SMTP server of your choice, but if you're willing for the scans to go over the internet and through Amazon SES you can do scan directly to email.